# I get an error when making tweak, where I used theos to create a template.

Tags: ios, macos, templates, terminal, tweak

I've been looking for a solution for several hours and I can't find a way to fix the error message, and I feel like I've tried everything!

Here is the error message I get when I create the tweak, within terminal on my Macbook:

```
svps-Mac:mytweak svp$ make
Making all for tweak mytweak...
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Can't call method "isNew" on an undefined value at /Users/svp/mytweak/theos/bin/logos.pl line 364.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.o] Error 22
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [mytweak.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
svps-Mac:mytweak svp$
```

Please help me!

Luka

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, turns out I didn't write the name of a certain method so it looked like this :p

```
- (void)
{
    //My Code
}
```

It may have been different for you but anyone who comes along this should look over their methods just in case

Answer (score -2):

Can't call method "isNew" on an undefined value at `/Users/svp/mytweak/theos/bin/logos.pl line 364.`

This is your problem on line 364 of your `logos.pl` file you didn't specify a `isNew` call method in the `.h` file like with an application you have to use a call method in the .h file and the other part of the code in the .mm file because you didn't do that it don't recognise the code.